# manipulate array of object within array of object base on property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I want to build certain UI, it involves manipulation of array object, I know the pseudo code, but I don't know how to produce the output. Below is my case statement. Need guidance.

if outer date is in between of data's date_from and date_to

```
[{
  date:'2017-05-11',
  data:[{id: 2, name: 'abc', date_from:'2017-05-03', date_to:'2017-05-05'}]
}]
```

set type to `mid`

```
[{
  date:'2017-05-11',
  data:[{id: 2, name: 'abc', date_from:'2017-05-03', date_to:'2017-05-05', type:'mid'}]
}]
```

if outer date is equal to date_from

```
[{
  date:'2017-05-11',
  data:[{id: 2, name: 'abc', date_from:'2017-05-11', date_to:'2017-05-15'}]
}]
```

set type to `is_start_left`

if outer date is equal to date_to

```
[{
  date:'2017-05-11',
  data:[{id: 2, name: 'abc', date_from:'2017-05-01', date_to:'2017-05-11'}]
}]
```

set type to `is_end_right`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested [conditional (ternary) Operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and check `date_from`, or `date_to` or return just `'mid'`.

```js
function setType(array) {
    array.forEach(a => a.data.forEach(o => o.type = a.date === o.date_from ?
        'is_start_left' :
        a.date === o.date_to ?
            'is_end_right' :
            'mid'
    ));
    return array;
}

console.log(setType([{ date: '2017-05-11', data: [{ id: 2, name: 'abc', date_from: '2017-05-03', date_to: '2017-05-05' }] }]));
console.log(setType([{ date: '2017-05-11', data: [{ id: 2, name: 'abc', date_from: '2017-05-11', date_to: '2017-05-15' }] }]));
console.log(setType([{ date: '2017-05-11', data: [{ id: 2, name: 'abc', date_from: '2017-05-01', date_to: '2017-05-11' }] }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: oh i see forEach within forEach. but i didn't know ternary operator can do multiple else.

Comment: @AlanJenshen, from this snippet, i hardly can tell where the error is.